# Combining fields, some null, in a textbox on a report in access

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to amalgamate a few address feilds into one text box on a report:

```
=[City]+", "+[County]+", "+[Post Code]
```

However not all records have an entry in the [County] column, which means that nothing shows in the textbox at all for these records. So I tried an Iif statement:

```
=IIf([County],[City]+", "+[County]+", "+[Post Code],[City]+", "+[Post Code])
```

This didn't work, how can I make the text box show whatever fields are present?

Comment: You want to show `City County Post Code`. So if Country is empty, isn't the textbox shows `City and PostCode`?

Comment: No if [County] is NULL but [City] and [Postcode] aren't, the textbox is blank.

Comment: +1 for triggering HansUp excellent answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were so close!

```
=[City]+", "+[County]+", "+[Post Code]
```

should be:

```
=[City]&", "&[County]&", "&[Post Code]
```

Remember, a NULL trumps everything in math, so using the plus operator was giving you a NULL result every time any field was blank.

Answer (score 6):

Easiest solution IMO: Use [Nz](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195223%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

```
=[City]+", "+Nz([County]+", ")+[Post Code]
```

Though you may want ot use `&` instead of `+`. In Access `+` means summation, but `&` means concatenation.

Comment: +1 But I still would not use + as a concatenator in VBA, unless I had something special in mind, in other words, only for the Nz. The VBA string concatentor is &.

Comment: @Remou, you only need another argument for Nz if you want something besides the default response on null. In most circumstances (personally) when dealing with string values, I want the default value so specifically indicating `, ""` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: You replied after I removed my comment :) I realized that after I clicked post :(

Answer (score 1):

you were close with your `IIf` statement.

You are missing one of 2 possible tests

if only nulls can appear,

```
=IIf(IsNull([County]),[City]+", "+[County]+", "+[Post Code],[City]+", "+[Post Code])
```

if it can be empty (`""`) or null

```
=IIf(len(""&[County]),[City]+", "+[County]+", "+[Post Code],[City]+", "+[Post Code])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the fact that the two concatenation operators (`+` and `&`) handle Nulls differently.

```
? "A" + Null
Null
? "A" & Null
A
```

So you could do this ...

```
? "A" & ", " & "B" & ", " & "C"
A, B, C
? "A" & ", " & Null & ", " & "C"
A, , C
```

... but if you don't want two commas when you have Null instead of the second string value, do this instead:

```
? "A" & (", " + Null) & ", " & "C"
A, C
```

If that all makes sense, apply the same pattern to your text box control source:

```
=[City] & (", " + [County]) & ", " & [Post Code]
```

You don't need functions (`IIf`, `IsNull`, `Len`, and/or `Nz`) to get what you want here.

Comment: Amazing ! Knowing that trick would have saved me quite some code !

Answer (score 0):

Try this please: Rather super ugly thought... When Chr(13) and Chr(10) are there it will never be empty.

```
IIf(Isnull([County]), 
    IIf(Isnull([Post Code]), 
        IIf(IsNull[Post Code]), "No Address", [Post Code]),
        [City] + Chr(13) & Chr(10) +[Post Code]),
[Country] + Chr(13) & Chr(10) + [City] + Chr(13) & Chr(10) +[Post Code])
```